# Bash Script to Change PDF Titles

Tags: bash, pdf, sed, command-line-interface

I need to change the title on many pdf files. Pdftk works great and I tried to create a bash script (pdftitle) to make it a single pass:

```
#!/bin/bash
newtitle=$2
pdftk "$1" data_dump output "$1".data.txt;
sed 's/^InfoKey:\sTitle\nInfoValue:\s.*/InfoKey:\sTitle\nInfoValue:'"$newtitle/" "$1".data.txt > "$1".data.fixed.txt;
pdftk "$1" update_info *.data.fixed.txt output "$1".fixed;
mv "$1".fixed "$1";
rm -f ./*.txt
exit;
```

So on the cli I would enter

**$> pdftitle mypdf.pdf "New Title"**

The data.txt that pdftk creates has multiple lines, but only two relevant lines are the targets:

```
...
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Author
InfoValue: Not Me
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Microsoft Word - Old Title.doc
InfoBegin
InfoKey: Creator
InfoValue: PScript5.dll Version 5.2
...
```

Of which the subsequent line needs to be replaced:

```
...
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: Relevant New Title
...
```

No error messages are produced but the title remains intact. So it seems that sed is having problems here, but I cannot figure out where or how.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without knowing which version of `sed` you're running, and on which standard library: `\s` itself isn't guaranteed to work (it's a PCRE extension; depending on arguments, `sed` is guaranteed to support only BRE or ERE syntax).

Comment: ...anyhow, can you build a reproducer that doesn't depend on `pdftk`, but just focuses on the `sed` bits where you're having trouble? That way other folks would be able to test their answers without having your PDFs, or without knowing a priori what pdftk output looks like. Consider a function that emits the output you need to transform, something like: `makeData() { printf '%s\n' 'InfoKey: Title' 'InfoValue: whatever' ...; }`, then `makeData | sed ...`, to generate a more standalone [mcve]. (Of course, you'd want to also explicitly specify desired output).

Comment: ...btw, `sed` often isn't the easiest/best tool to use whet matching more than a single line. It's often easier to use `awk`, or even native bash string manipulation primitives.

Comment: @Charles Duffy - Thank you for the prompt reply. I'm using Linux Mint KDE and sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2. As for not using pdftk and relying solely on sed, I'm not a programmer and I'm not sure I understand completely what you are instructing me to do on your second comment.

Comment: They are instructions for how to articulate a better question. Your PDF tool isn't really relevant here; your specific problem is how to change particular lines in a text file.

Comment: A further search seems to indicate that awk or perl are, indeed, better solutions to find and replace the strings that pdftk outputs. Any suggestions on how to target a single line based on the preceding 'nominating' line? In this case, I need to find 'Infokey: Title' and act on the following line.

Comment: As an aside, a script which does `rm ./*.txt` as a side effect is a terrible design. If `pdftk` is any good in can accept the new data on standard input so you don't need to commit any temporary data to disk.

Comment: `awk -v title="Your Title Here" '/^InfoKey: Title/ { t=1} t && /^InfoValue:/ { $0 = "InfoValue: " title; t=0 }1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a refactoring using Awk which assumes `pdftk` can write to and read from stdin/stdout using `-` as the pseudo-filename argument.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
shift
pdftk "$filename" data_dump output - |
awk -v title="$*" '/^InfoKey: Title/ { t=1 }
    t && /^InfoValue:/ { $0 = "InfoValue: " title; t=0 }1' |
pdftk "$filename" update_info - output "$filename".fixed &&
mv "$filaname".fixed "$filename"
```

The pattern to set a flag variable when you see a pattern and then acting on a subsequent line if that variable is set is a simple and very common Awk idiom.

There is no need for trailing semicolons or an explicit `exit` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee! your solution worked perfectly after a couple of tweaks.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, completely agree, I realized this after I had closed my computer yesterday. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee provided the solution to make the bash script work perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
shift
pdftk "$filename" data_dump output |
awk -v title="$@" '/^InfoKey: Title/ { t=1 }
t && /^InfoValue:/ { $0 = "InfoValue: " title; t=0 }1' > data.txt
pdftk "$filename" update_info data.txt output "$filename".fixed &&
mv "$filename".fixed "$filename"
rm ./data.txt
```

Comment: You'll want the `$*` fix here too.